# Find common text within a range of cells(range containing blanks as well)

Tags: excel-formula

This is the problem i am facing in Excel formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYgk1.png)

In column F, i want to find the common text across A2 to E2 (containing Blanks)

My Question:
Is there a simple way to get the result without VB?
Any help is appreciated,thanks

Comment: Does this have to be in a single cell? Also, how big are the strings? I think there might be a brute force way, but it’s not really practical of the strings are big, or has to fit in a smaller amount of cells.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single cell. I can use TEXTJOIN to add them later.
Strings are not that big. It can go from just 1 to 16 variants of MSxx (Like MS01 till MS16). But the columns can go over a 100.

Comment: all the entries that you want to check will be separated by commas? and this is for each row? also, is it possible that there will be no common text?

Comment: Yes, all entries are separated by commas. Yes for each row. There will be no common text inside one cell.

Answer (score 0):

I found that google sheets has some really cool functions.

If you put the formula  `=SPLIT(A1, ",", TRUE,FALSE)` in the cell after your row of common text (or probably even in a different sheet - "probably because hadn't tried it, though it should), the next x cells (where x is the number of "," in A1 - because "," is the delimitator) will be the text.

then you can put the code `=IF(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(if(REGEXMATCH($A$1:$D$1,F1),1,0)))=COUNTA($A$1:$D$1),F1,"")` into an equal number of cells after that (probably should just put into the max number), and `=CONCATENATE(I1:L1)` into the last cell.

Ok. So to tweak this for yourself: I found that ARRAYFORMULA lets you put an array in place of a single cell in a function inside. how it exactly works I read its like a for loop. but I can't really vouch for that. but here it lets you have REGEXMATCH (which is a Boolean check on the cell you give it for if it contains the given REGEX) check each cell in the array.

the sum will add them up, and the if will match against the COUNTA to find if the number of cells in the array that contain this string is equal to the number of non-empty cells.

the concatenate at the end adds all the cells (containing the regex function) together, and since the only non-empty cells will be the one with the string, that is what this cell will return (no spaces).

code:
[image: code]
results:
[image: results]
the test data:

[image: test data]

If you need in specifically Excel... this won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the help Doragon. I will need this specifically in Excel. But i will try in sheets as well and copy over the data into Excel. Thanks for the effort. :)

Comment: This method did not help me as i have more than 100 columns of strings. Splitting them separately is not viable as i have more than 10000 rows worth of data.

Comment: don't split them all. Just split the first one. If its not in the first one, it cant be in all of them.

Comment: the first one can be empty too. There are 100 columns, and 98 of them can be empty and they can vary.

Comment: this will help excel for the split part: don't use split. If you are checking only up to 16 possibilities, just check all 16 possibilities. (enter the 16 possibilities in 16 cells, and continue as if the "split" function had returned that.

Comment: yeah, sorry i might have led you to wrong assumption. There can be a million combinations. What i meant by MS01 to MS16, it can be (MS01,MS03,MS14), (MS01,MS02,MS10) etc..... so there are so many combinations that this method is not viable.

Comment: but are you only checking which of the MS01...MS16 are in there? this method will return whichever (and all) of the MS.. are in every cell. If you want the whole cell to appear, wouldn't you already have that? Are you trying to find which errors exist in the list?

Answer (score 0):

We can use power query to achieve the desired result.

1. Unpivot the columns in Power query
2. Split all the columns by Comma delimiter
3. Create a custom column to see if the first column records exist in the remaining columns.
   Use the function`Text.contains`.
   Sample function: `=Text.Contains([column.1],[column.1]&[column.2]&[column.3])`
4. If the above function returns `TRUE` then get the first column result(This is the expected result) and load the data back to your excel

Comment: I have no experience with Power query in Excel. I will try to follow the same steps as you have mentioned and get this to work in excel.

Comment: Sample function: =Text.Contains([column.1],[column.1]&[column.2]&[column.3])
Having & in the function, is returning an error. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: how do you split by comma delimiter in Excel with functions? this isn't a vba question.

Comment: never mind. found this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/       looks kind of annoying though, since you must change it for each of the 16 possibilities

Comment: I don't see the function "Text.contains" in Excel's formula documentation. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188#bm20

Comment: Text.Contains is an M query function in Powerquery. It is not an excel function.